# $f$ bounded but $f'$ isn't

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is there a bounded function $f$ that holomorphic on the open unit disc but $f'$ isn't bounded?

I think first $f$ shouldn't be analytic outside the unit disc then we can't use Cauchy's inequality, because 
$$|f'(z)|\le\frac{\max|f|}{R}$$
When $z$ near the bound of unit disc $R$ should be small so $|f'(z)|$ can be large

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$(z+1)\log(z+1)$ is bounded on the open unit disk $|z|\lt1$. Its derivative, $1+\log(z+1)$ is not.

Answer (score 6):

Any branch of $\sqrt{1+z}$ is bounded in the unit disk,
but the derivative $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+z}}$ is not.

Comment: +1 Similar idea to $(z+1)\log(z+1)$: the antiderivative of a function that blows up slower than $\frac1{x+1}$ at $x=-1$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work? $$\sum_n \frac{x^{2^n}}{2^n}$$