# Problem regarding zeros and poles of a meromorphic function inside a circle (Argument Principle)

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Basically, I have confusion when I am going through the Argument Principle from the book of [Stein & Shakarchi](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Complex_Analysis.html?id=0ECHh9tjPUAC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> Suppose, f is meromorphic in a region $\Omega$ and $C$ be a circle
>   inside $\Omega$ containing its interior. Let, $z_1,z_2,...,z_m$ and
>   $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ be the zeros and poles of $f$ inside $C$
>   respectively and $f$ doesn't have any zero or pole on $C$ (i.e. on the
>   boundary).

In the book, the author proves that if a holomorphic and not identically zero function $f$ has a zero (say $z_0$) in $\Omega$. Then $\exists$ a neighbourhood (say $D(z_0)$) of $z_0$ in $\Omega$ and a unique $p\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $f(z)=(z-z_0)^pg(z)\ \forall z\in D(z_0)$ where $g$ is a non-vanishing holomorphic function on $D(z_0)$.
As a corollary, he also shows that if $f$ has a pole (say $w_0$) in $\Omega$. Then $\exists$ a neighbourhood (say $D(w_0)$) of $w_0$ in $\Omega$ and a unique $q\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $f(z)=(z-w_0)^{-q}h(z)\ \forall z\in D(w_0)$ where $h$ is a non-vanishing holomorphic function on $D(w_0)$.
So, these statements holds locally i.e. **existance of the functions $g$ or $h$ is in a neighbourhood of the zero or pole. And even these are proved for either one pole or one zero separately.** 
But to prove the result of Argument principle i.e. ${1\over2\pi i}\int_{C} {f'(z)\over f(z)}dz=$(#of zeros with multiplicity)$-$(#of poles with multiplicity), we need to establish the fact that
$f(z)=\prod_{i=1}^{m}(z-z_i)^{p_i}\prod_{j=1}^{n}(z-w_j)^{-q_j}G(z)\ \forall z\in C\cup\operatorname{int}C$ and $G$ is non-vanishing, holomorphic in $C\cup\operatorname{int}C$.
So, that I can get holomorphic $G'/G$ on $C\cup\operatorname{int}C$ and $\int_{C}{G'(z)\over G(z)}dz=0$
But I can't prove this. Can anybody give me explanation to remove the confussion. Thnaks for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we define$$G(z)=\prod_{j=1}^m(z-z_j)^{-p_j}\prod_{k=1}^n(z-w_k)^{q_k}f(z),$$for each $z\in\Omega$, then $G$ is a holomorphic function without zeros or poles and therefore $\frac{G'}G$ is a holomorphic function.

Comment: I have another query. Number of poles of $f$ inside $C$ is finite due to meromorphic property and $C\cup\operatorname{int}C$ is compact hence BW-compact. But what about number of zeros? Can there be infinitely many zeros of meromorphic $f$ inside $C$?

Comment: No, because $C\cup\operatorname{int}C$ is compact and, in a compact set, every infinite set has a accumulation point.

Comment: Yes, it is right. As per the definition of Meromorphic function the set of points where $f$ had poles must not contain any accumulation point in domain. But what about zeros? I'm asking about the zeros

Comment: Me too. If $z_0$ is an accumulation point of the set of zeros, then $z_0\in C$ or $z_o\in\operatorname{int}C$. If $z_0\in\operatorname{int}C$, then $f$ is the null function. And you don't have zeros in $C$.

Comment: Yes  Got it, thanks